# Lock position of Object on a layer but NOT the whole layer

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am using Illustrator 2018 on Windows.

I have a layer with multiple elements on it (different text boxes and some shapes).

Is it possible to lock the position of a individual element but not the whole layer?

Many thanks

Comment: Yea, you can lock objects, though it's not just a position lock. You can read more from [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/locking-hiding-deleting-objects.html#lock_or_unlock_objects_or_layers).

Answer (score 1):

Select the **object** and choose `Object > Lock` from the menu.

Or....

Find the **object in the Layers Panel** and click the lock icon to the left of the object on the panel.

[image]